# What's the difference between (mymacro arg) and (eval (myfunc (quote arg)))

Tags: macros, lisp, eval

The way I 'see' macros in Lisp is the following: whenever I see a macro call `(mymacro arg1 arg2 ... argn)`, I assume it is the same as `(eval (myfun (quote arg1) (quote arg2) ... (quote argn)))`, where myfun is a function whose body is *exactly* the same as the body of mymacro.I imagine that this is an over simplistic way of understanding macros. But I'm having trouble finding an example where it fails.

So, is there an example of s-expressions BODY and ARG such that, given the following definitions of `mymacro` and `myfun`,

```
(defmacro mymacro (param) BODY) 
(defun    myfun   (param) BODY)
```

the expressions
`(mymacro ARG)` and `(eval (myfun (quote ARG)))`
do *not* evaluate to the same result?

PS: I am using just one parameter so it's easier to write this question, but I'm obviously fine with examples with multiple parameters.

PS: I am more interested in the semantic difference at the end, than on implementation details, performance differences etc.

Answer (score 2):

> *But I'm having trouble finding an example where it fails.*

```
(defmacro plus-mac (left right)
  `(+ ,left ,right))

(defun plus-expander (left right)
  `(+ ,left ,right))
```

Then:

```
(let ((a 3) (b 4))
  (plus-mac a b))  ;; -> 7, works!

(let ((a 3) (b 4))
  (eval (plus-expander 'a 'b))) ;; fail: variables a and b not defined
```

You have read somewhere a description of macros similar to "macros are replaced with code that is evaluated in their place, which is produced by their expander function", and have taken it too literally.

Macros are replaced, but the expansion is not evaluated; an `eval` call is not inserted at that spot in the code.

Firstly, macros are usually expanded before the code is evaluated. Those two actions can be quite separate. For instance, macros might be expanded on a developer's build machine, whereas evaluation takes place when the program is run on the user's target machine.

Even if a macro is expanded immediately before the expression is evaluated, that evaluation is not done by an `eval` call inserted into the code. That would not properly work with lexical scoping, as my above example shows.

Lastly, macros (the unhygienic, Common-Lisp-style ones we are talking about which perform simple substitution) do not work under the hood the way it is imagined in the question. A macro call like `(mac a b (c d (e)))` results in an expander function being called. That function has two arguments: the entire macro form, and a macro-time environment. The separation of the macro syntax into the arguments `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` and `e` is done by code which is written by `defmacro`.  The expander looks something like:

```
(lambda (form env)
  (destructuring-bind (#:operator a b (c d (e))) form
    ... body goes here ...))
```

That is still not accurate because `destructuring-bind` wouldn't produce good diagnostics.  Destructuring lambda lists and macro lambda lists are similar, but not the same. This is just for illustration purposes to show that `defmacro` inserts destructuring code around the body of your macro; that code receives the entire macro call form via one argument, and sets up the local variables that hold the named pieces.

If you want to peek under the hood, try expanding a `defmacro` call to see what code it generates:

```
(macroexpand '(defmacro mac (a b (c d (e))) (list a b c d e)))
```

Answer (score 1):

It will be different if the expansion references local variables, since `eval` evaluates the expression in the global environment.

Here's a macro that's a simplified version of the standard `INCF` macro.

```
(defun increment-func (variable) 
  `(setq ,variable (1+ ,variable)))

(defmacro increment (variable) 
  (increment-func variable))

(let ((foo 1))
  (increment foo)
  (print foo))

(let ((foo 1))
  (eval (increment-func 'foo)))
```

The first use will work and print `2`, the second will complain that `FOO` is unbound.

Answer (score 0):

Macros can also be used to represent things that are not valuable, like bindings or tagbody labels, etc. For example, here is a macro that implements a block that iterates over the key/values of an hash-table:

```lisp
(defmacro hash-iter ((key value &optional result) hash &body body)
  `(block nil
     (maphash (lambda (,key ,value) ,@body) ,hash)
     ,result))
```

You can use it as follows:

```lisp
(let ((my-hash (alexandria:alist-hash-table '((:a . 0) (:b . 1)))))
  (hash-iter (k v) my-hash
    (declare (ignore k))
    (print v)))
```

This prints:

```
0
1
```

Here below, the arguments `k` and `v` submitted to the macro are symbols that are used to bind values, it doesn't make sense to evaluate them.

Answer (score 0):

This is generally how macros are implemented under the hood. The difference is *when* the two forms get evaluated. You don't say which lisp language you are using, but here's an example in Common Lisp:

```lisp
(defparameter counter 1)

(defmacro macro (a)
  (setf counter (+ a counter)))

(defun func (a)
  (setf counter (+ a counter)))

(defun test ()
  (macro 1))

(progn 
  (func 1)
  (test)
  (test)
  (test)
  (func 1))
```

If you evaluate this in order, the `progn` returns 4. However, if you were going to use the form you suggested:

```lisp
(defparameter counter 1)

(defun test2 ()
  (eval (func 1)))

(progn 
  (func 1)
  (test2)
  (test2)
  (test2)
  (func 1))
```

You get 6. This is because macros are only evaluated once at compile time, whereas functions are always evaluated. The difference in the counter is because each subsequent evaluations of `test2` increment the counter, but the counter in `test2` is incremented at once compile time. Calling the `test` function actually has no effect at all on the counter value.

I highly recommend reading [Macros: Defining Your Own](https://gigamonkeys.com/book/macros-defining-your-own.html) to get a better understanding of how and why macros are useful.

If you do want to learn more about the implementation details, playing around with Common Lisp's [`macro-function`](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Body/acc_macro-function.html) can be enlightening, as it allows you to access the actual function that is used to expand a given expression. You can use `nil` for the environment parameter in the function returned by `macro-function`

```lisp
(funcall (macro-function 'macro) `(1) nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring details about arglist destructuring by `defmacro` and so on since this is a question about Lisp and not Common Lisp, this will fail in exactly the cases where *x* is not semantically the same as `(eval (quote` *x*`))`.  So, for instance, it will fail any time there are lexical bindings.

---

(This could be 'fixed' in some hypothetical Lisp by making environments first-class and perhaps allowing `eval` to have two optional arguments for the current lexical and dynamic environments.  It should be very obvious that this is bad news for optimising compilers.)